# How to create constant numeric value expression in QueryDSL?

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, querydsl

I'd like to create query like this with QueryDSL

```
update WorkMessage w set w.totalPrice = 0.12 - w.totalCost;
```

I tried like this

```
    Expression<Float> priceExpr = Expressions.constant(0.12f);

    new JPAUpdateClause(em, w)
            .set(w.totalPrice , priceExpr.subtract(w.totalCost));
```

But this doesn't work - Expression doesn't have subtract method.

I did it like this:

```
        new JPAUpdateClause(em, w)
            .set(w.totalPrice , w.totalCost.subtract(0.12f).negate());
```

but I'd like to know how to do it the first way.

//EDit

The second way don't work:

JPAUpdateClause.toString says:

```
update WorkMessage workMessage 
set workMessage.totalPrice = -(workMessage.totalCost - :a1)
```

but the SQL result is

```
update work_message set total_price=-total_cost-?
```

Parentheses just dissapeared. Am I doing something wrong? It looks like theese:

```
w.totalCost.subtract(0.12f).negate()
w.totalCost.negate().subtract(0.12f)
```

have the same result.

For the above problem

```
w.totalCost.negate().add(0.12f)
```

works. But I think there is a bug.

Comment: Could you open a ticket for it on GitHub : https://github.com/mysema/querydsl/issues

Comment: QueryDSL works OK. It's a Hibernate bug. update WorkMessage workMessage set workMessage.earnedPrice = - ( workMessage.totalCost - :a1 ) translates into  update work_message set earned_price=-total_cost-?

Comment: I thought it was something with QueryDSL but it is related to Hibernate itself. Created an issue https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6714 . Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We removed the DSL Constant types some time ago from Querydsl. If you really want to write it the first way, then you have to express it like this :

```
Expressions.operation(Float.class, Ops.SUB, 
    Expressions.constant(0.12f), w.totalCost)
```

or

```
NumberOperation.create(Float.class, Ops.SUB, 
    Expressions.constant(0.12f), w.totalCost)
```

if you need a NumberExpression

Comment: Thanks Timo. Could You look at //Edit part above?

Comment: What was the reason there are no constant number-expressions? I really need a NumberExpression<Integer> with value zero now.

Comment: The reasons were unnecessary API complexity  and maintenance overhead. NumberTemplate.ZERO should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem some time ago (needed the constant 0), and did build my own ConstantNumberExpression class. It turned out surprisingly easy :-)

A collegue just had the same problem, for the constant 1, so I decided to post it here.

```
private static class ConstantNumberExpression extends NumberExpression<Integer> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1220768215234001828L;

    public ConstantNumberExpression(final int constant) {
        super(new ConstantImpl<>(constant));
    }

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public <R, C> R accept(final Visitor<R, C> v, @Nullable final C context) {
        return v.visit((Constant<Integer>) mixin, context);
    }
}
```

Of course this could be done a bit more generic, using a type parameter, but we did need it only for Integer (actually only for zero and one).

Comment: In this case you can use com.mysema.query.types.Constant or ConstantImpl